# How to signal a thread in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

I am working on multi-threaded application where I am using `SetEvent()` to close the thread on windows.

What is the equivalent in linux c++ to send a signal to a thread? The application has to run on both windows and linux.

In windows, I am doing the following:

In the UI I have a button say **Close thread**. Once the user press the button it will set the event using `SetEvent()` which causes the thread to stop it self.

```
void closethread()
{
    Setevent(hEventhandle);
}


void * threadProc(void* args)
{
    waitforsingleobject(hEventhandle,infintie)
}
```

Is there any better to way close the thread when the user presses the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a cross-platform GUI application, you probably already use some cross-platform GUI framework, like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). These frameworks usually come with their own cross-platform libraries for all sorts of things, including multi-threading. So instead of using native APIs, check out the documentation of the framework you (hopefully) use.

Alternatively, you can consider using [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html) to handle the multi-threading in a portable way.

Comment: @Chris_vr: Qt has a thread-safe signaling mechanism built in, so you should probably just use that.

Comment: I Dont know QT can you give link related with QT event management api and example

Answer (score 2):

You could use a condition variable - see e.g. [pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html)

Comment: If you want to remain ignorant, go with QT / wx. If you actually want to *know* how to do simple things on multiple platforms without resorting to thick wrappers, read up on pthreads.